# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 0$ proof with $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis

I have read, that you can proof $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 0$ with using $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$

I know that $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is equal to $n^{\frac{ln(ln(n))-ln(n)}{n}}$, but I don't know how I could use $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ to find the limit... Any hints?

Comment: $n^{1/n}=e^{(\ln n)/n}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$n^{\frac1n}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

By continuity of $log$ function, $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log n^{\frac{1}{n}} = \log 1=0$. Hence you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry...

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ and $n^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}$, hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ must be $0$ because of $e^0 = 1$